# Service restarts when killing activity process

Tags: android, android-service

I have an activity that starts a service in a seperate process via the `android:process` attributes of my service.

My service's `onStartCommand()` function returns `START_STICkY`.

I kill my activity's process through swiping it away via the recent apps button, and the service process restarts.

I want to know if there is a way to keep the service running when the activity process is killed.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @Perry_ml No unfortunately. I have dropped this project.

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to know if there is a way to keep the service running when the activity process is killed.
```

**No, there is no way to keep the service running.** Because,

```
Closed by the user via the Running Services screen in Settings.

Closed by the user via a task killer.

Closed by Android to free up memory in times of need.
```

[**Keep the service running is BAD idea.**](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/)

But you can do,

--> you can restart you service using **BROADCAST RECEIVER**.(when incoming call, BOOT complete, SMS received.. etc, use this depend on your requirement)